# In Mongo, how do I only display documents with the highest value for a key that they share?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Say I have the following four documents in a collection called "Store":

```
{ item: 'chair', modelNum: 1154, votes: 75 }
{ item: 'chair', modelNum: 1152, votes: 16 }
{ item: 'table', modelNum: 1017, votes: 24 }
{ item: 'table', modelNum: 1097, votes: 52 }
```

I would like to find only the documents with the highest number of votes for each item type.
The result of this simple example would return modelNum: 1154 and modelNum: 1097.  Showing me the most popular model of chair and table, based on the customer inputed vote score.

What is the best way write this query and sort them by vote in descending order?  I'm developing using meteor, but I don't think that should have an impact.

```
Store.find({????}).sort({votes: -1});
```

Comment: Are you asking about `find` within the meteor app or from a mongo shell?  Chaining the options, like `.sort()` above, is the mongo shell format.

Comment: I'm a bit new to Meteor, so I suppose what I'm asking is -- what is the best way to display only the top vote getters of each item using Meteor.  I assume it would be something like:

Template.itemsList.helpers({
    items: function () {
        return Store.find(???);
    }
});

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$first`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) or [`$last`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last) aggregation operators to achieve what you want.  These operators are only useful when `$group` follows `$sort`.  An example using `$first`:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Sort by "item" ASC, "votes" DESC
    {"$sort" : {item : 1, votes : -1}}, 
    // Group by "item" and pick the first "modelNum" (which will have the highest votes)
    {"$group" : {_id : "$item", modelNum : {"$first" : "$modelNum"}}}
])
```

Here's the output:

```js
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "table",
                        "modelNum" : 1097
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "chair",
                        "modelNum" : 1154
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to do this in Meteor and on the client I would just use an each loop and basic find.  Minimongo keeps the data in memory so I don't think additional `find` calls are expensive.

like this:

```
 Template.itemsList.helpers({
   items: function(){
     var itemNames = Store.find({}, {fields: {item: 1}}).map( 
       function( item ) { return item.item; }
     );
     var itemsMostVotes = _.uniq( itemNames ).map( 
       function( item ) {
         return Store.findOne({item: item}, {sort: {votes: -1}});
       }
     );
     return itemsMostVotes;
   }
 });
```

I have switched to `findOne` so this returns an array of objects rather than a cursor as `find` would.  If you really want the cursor then you could query minimongo with the _ids from itemMostVotes.

You could also use the [underscore groupBy and sortBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692965/group-by-queries-on-meteor-collection/21693303#21693303) functions to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the aggregation framework.

So

```
db.Store.aggregate(
    {$group:{_id:"$item", "maxVotes": {$max:"$votes"}}}
);
```

Comment: That doesn't return the model #s that match and further, Meteor doesn't support aggregations directly.

Comment: That was the issue I hit. I believe aggregations and Map/Reduce were avoided in Meteor because they would have prevented live updating.  Is there a way within Meteor to accomplish this and keep the live update functionality? It seems like such a simple and common query.

Comment: I actually am not too familiar with Meteor, didn't know aggregate wasn't supported. Would like to get this answered myself actually.