# Complex mongodb transform in Meteor, is annotation behavior possible?`

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am looking for the best way to get the following result: I need to get a list of the most recent Inventories per Location and then sort them by timestamp.

Here are the models:

```
Location:
   _id: "someID"
   beverages: 
      _id: "someID"
      fillTo: "87"
      name: "Beer"
      orderWhen: "87"
      startUnits: "87"
   name: "Second"
   number: "102"
   organization: "The Second One"

Inventories:
    _id: "someID"
        beverages:
            0: Object
            name: "Diet Coke"
            units: "88"
    location: "someID"
    timestamp: 1397622495615
    user_id: "someID"
```

So, in Django with Postgres, I would have added an annotation to each Location using Max for an "latestInventory" annotation. Then I would just push only the Inventories per Location that have a latestInventory into a set (dictionary). But that is because I had the ability to find those relations easily with Django's ORM.

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this with mongodb in Meteor?

I think I will need to use a transform, yes?

Comment: OK, now that I think about it a bit more, I think it makes sense to first get all Locations and sort by _id, then remove all but the most recent Inventory from each Location. How do I do that?

Comment: Inventories.find({}, {sort: {location: -1, timestamp: 1}}), gets me most of the way there, now I just need to remove all but the most recent Inventory. Any ideas?

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23050276/728291)

Comment: Ah dude, I would give you the solution if you replied instead of commenting. Great solution! Not at all easy!