# Group simple Meteor Collection by field

Tags: meteor, collections

This question has been asked in different forms before but I have never found a simple concise answer.

I have a basic collection for use in my template:

```
Template.snackPage.helpers({

  snacks: function() {
    return Snacks.find({}, {sort: {day: 1}});
  }

});
```

Which returns something like this:

```
{
    {day: "04-05-2016", title: "Oranges"},
    {day: "04-05-2016", title: "Bananas"},
    {day: "07-05-2016", title: "Grapes"},
    {day: "07-05-2016", title: "Herrings"},
    {day: "09-05-2016", title: "Mint slices"},
}
```

I want to list it in my template by day heading like this:

```
Day: 04-05-2016
    - Oranges
    - Bananas

Day: 07-05-2016
    - Grapes
    - Herrings

Day: 09-05-2016
    - Mint slices
```

My question is how do I do this while maintaining reactivity and with least overhead/fuss :)

Answer (score 1):

Underscores [_.groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) might work for this. You could also look into using the Mongo aggregation pipleline: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/

Heres a similar SO question: ["group by" queries on meteor collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692965/group-by-queries-on-meteor-collection)

Comment: I think using _.groupBy means casting it to an array first and losing reactivity?