# How can find sort and total?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How can I find this field (order by) and total vote on mongodb, I use meteor mongo. this my code

```
Posts.find({},{limit: 5, sort: {vote: -1,owner:-1}});
```

it's not work

```
{
    "_id":123,
    "owner":"yuda",
    "vote":12
}
{
    "_id":124,
    "owner":"yuda",
    "vote":3
}
{
    "_id":125,
    "owner":"lucy",
    "vote":42
}
```

i need result sort by owner and total vote:

```
{
    "owner":"lucy",
    "vote":42
}
{
    "owner":"yuda",
    "vote":15
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should produce the correct result:

```js
// fetch some posts
var posts = Posts.find({}, {limit: 5}).fetch();

// track the count of votes by owner
var votesByOwner = {};

// determine the count of votes by owner
_.each(posts, function(post) {
  if (votesByOwner[post.owner] == null)
    votesByOwner[post.owner] = 0;
  votesByOwner[post.owner] += post.vote;
});

// reshape and sort the vote data
var result = _.chain(votesByOwner)
  .map(function(votes, owner) {return {owner: owner, votes: votes};})
  .sortBy('owner')
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

Also see this related question: ["group by" queries on meteor collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692965/group-by-queries-on-meteor-collection).